# Idiomatic way to implement "services" in F#

Tags: f#

When working in F# and implementing a "service" pattern, such as wrappers around web APIs or databases or USB gadgets, what's the idiomatic way to do this?  My inclination is to use e.g. `IDatabase` and `Database`, `ITwitter` and `Twitter`, `ICamera` and `Camera` interfaces and classes just like in C#, allowing for easy test mocks.  But I don't want to code "C# in F#" if that's not the standard way to do it.

I considered using DU's, to represent e.g. `Camera | TestCamera`, but that means putting all the mock code into the production codebase, which sounds horrible.  But maybe that's just my OO background speaking.

I also considered making `IDatabase` a record of functions.  I'm still open to that idea, but it seems a bit contrived.  Plus it rules out the idea of ever using an IoC controller, or any "MEF-like" plugin capability (at least that I'm aware of).

What's the "idiomatic F#" way of doing this?  Just follow the C# service pattern?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32411667/126014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using interfaces in F#.

The textbook FP approach would be to have the client take functions that implement the logic of your component as arguments, but that approach doesn't scale nicely as the number of those functions grows. Grouping them together is a good idea as it improves readability, and using interfaces for that is an idiomatic way of doing it in .NET. It makes sense especially on the boundary of well-defined components, and I think the three interfaces you cite fit that description well.

I've seen DU's used roughly the way you described (providing both production and a fake implementation), but it doesn't sit well with me either.

If anything, records of functions are not idiomatic. They're a poor man's way of bundling together behaviour in FP languages, but if there's one thing object oriented languages do right, it's bundling together behaviour. Interfaces are just a better tool for the job, especially since F# lets you create implementations inline with object expression syntax.

Comment: Accepted because it was first and it covers the main case; the other answers were details based on this one.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the other answer, using interfaces is fine in F# and that might be a good way to solve the problem. However, if you use more functional transformation-oriented style of programming, you may not need them.

Ideally, most of the actual interesting code should be transformations that do not perform any effects - and so they do not invoke any services. Instead, they just take inputs and produce outputs. Let me demonstrate using a database.

Using a `IDatabase` service, you might write something like this:

```
let readAveragePrice (database:IDatabase) = 
  [ for p in database.GetProducts() do
      if not p.IsDiscontinued then
        yield p.Price ]
  |> Seq.average
```

When written like this, you can provide a mock implementation of `IDatabase` to test that the averaging logic in `readAveragePrice` is correct. However, you can also write the code like this:

```
let calculateAveragePrice (products:seq<Product>) = 
  [ for p in products do
      if not p.IsDiscontinued then
        yield p.Price ]
  |> Seq.average
```

Now you can test `calculateAveragePrice` without any mocking - just give it some sample products that you want to process! This is pushing the data access out from the core logic to the outside. So you'd have:

```
database.GetProducts() |> calculateAveragePrice // Actual call in the system
[ Product(123.4) ] |> calculateAveragePrice     // Call on sample data in the test
```

Of course, this is a simplistic example, but it shows the idea:

> Push the data access code outside of the core logic and keep the core logic as pure functions that implement transformations. Then your core logic will be easy to test - given sample inputs, they should return the correct results!

Answer (score 6):

While other people here write that there's nothing wrong with using interfaces in F#, I consider interfaces nothing more than an interop mechanism that enables F# to work with code written in the other .NET languages.

When I write code in C#, I follow the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). When used together, the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) should ultimately [drive you towards defining as small-grained interfaces as possible](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional).

Thus, even in C#, **properly designed interfaces should have only a single method**:

```
public interface IProductQuery
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int categoryId);
}
```

Furthermore, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) implies that "clients [...] own the abstract interfaces" ([APPP](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk), chapter 11), which means that artificial **bundles of methods is a poor design** anyway.

The only reason to define an interface like the above `IProductQuery` is that in C#, interfaces are still the best mechanism for polymorphism.

In F#, on the other hand, there's no reason to define a single-member interface. **Use a function instead**.

You can pass in functions as arguments to other functions:

```
let calculateAveragePrice getProducts categoryId = 
    categoryId
    |> getProducts
    |> Seq.filter (fun p -> not p.IsDiscontinued)
    |> Seq.map (fun p -> p.Price)
    |> Seq.average
```

In this example, you'll notice that `getProducts` is passed as an argument to the `calculateAveragePrice` function, and its type is not even declared. This fits beautifully with the principle of letting the client define the interface: the **type of the argument is inferred from the client's usage**. It has the type `'a -> #seq<Product>` (because `categoryId` can be any generic type `'a`).

Such a function as `calculateAveragePrice` is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), which is a Functional thing to do.

Comment: I see the reasoning and logic but have trouble with the conclusion.  Given records are bundles of `get_` methods, does that mean they're a poor design too?  Where/why does the line get drawn?  That's probably a longer conversation though.

Comment: On to specifics, take the `ICamera` example, currently `getNewPhoto camera config` has to call several `camera.setWhatever cfg.whatever`, `camera.snap()`, `camera.awaitFile`, and `camera.download`.  Seems clunky to pass each of those methods as N individual parameters to `getNewPhoto`.  How would you recommend handling something like that?

Comment: (n.b. the `getNewPhoto` function gets used in many different places, so I don't think it would be prudent to break up into fewer-parameter chunks and inline those everywhere.)

Comment: As I also wrote in http://stackoverflow.com/q/32411667/126014 if you need to pass all those functions as arguments to the same function, it could be a sign that that function does too much. This, too, has an equivalent in SOLID when you combine the SRP and the ISP.

Comment: "records are bundles of get_ methods" That's only true if you consider the IL-level implementation. Records are bundles of *values*, not methods. Those `get` methods could have been implemented as fields instead, and it would have made no difference.

Comment: But if the function is getting used in lots of places, even if it's doing lots of things, or perhaps *especially* if it's doing lots of things, doesn't it make more sense to keep it self-contained rather than inlining it everywhere?  Is there a third option I'm missing?

Comment: All pure functions are self-contained... I don't understand the question...(?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89659/discussion-between-lobsterism-and-mark-seemann).